# Android SOAP envelope modification

Tags: android, xml, soap

The application creates the following request XML:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <v:Header />
  <v:Body>
   some body...
  </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

and I **need** it to prepare this kind of request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    some body...
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The most important is in the first string, it should start with `xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` instead of `xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`

How to change it in:

```
try {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            request.addProperty("entity", "persona");
            request.addProperty("last_update_date", "20140101");
            request.addProperty("country", "UA");
            request.addProperty("user", "someuser");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        Log.i(TAG, "Envelope to String: \n" + String.valueOf(envelope));
        Log.i(TAG, "request to String: \n" + String.valueOf(request));

            envelope.implicitTypes = true;
            envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
            envelope.dotNet = true;

            envelope.bodyOut = request;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportBasicAuth androidHttpTransport = null;

            try 
            {

                androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportBasicAuth(URL, null, null);
                androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

                } 
        catch (SoapFault e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "2 HTTP REQUEST:\n" + androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
            Log.d(TAG, "2 HTTP RESPONSE:\n" + androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
            SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception REQUEST:\n" + androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
            Log.d(TAG, "BodyIn #2 \n" + resultsRequestSOAP);
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception RESPONSE:\n" + androidHttpTransport.responseDump);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

This is a logcat trace:

```
06-25 12:50:58.955: I/ENVELOPE_BODY(24323): XMLDataGet{property1=value1; property2=value2; property3=value3; property4=value4; }

06-25 12:50:59.630: D/GetInfo(24323): Exception REQUEST:
06-25 12:50:59.630: D/GetInfo(24323): <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header /><v:Body><XMLDataGet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><property1>value1</property1><property2>value2</property2><property3>value3</property3><property4>value4</property4></XMLDataGet></v:Body></v:Envelope>


06-25 12:50:59.635: D/GetInfo(24323): BodyIn 
06-25 12:50:59.635: D/GetInfo(24323): null


06-25 12:50:59.635: D/GetInfo(24323): Exception RESPONSE:
06-25 12:50:59.635: D/GetInfo(24323): <s:Envelope xmlns:s="https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><XMLDataGetResponse xmlns="https://tempuri.org/"><XMLDataGetResult><ItemList xmlns="">....the whole data structure...</ItemList></XMLDataGetResult></XMLDataGetResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>

06-25 12:57:26.500: W/System.err(25523): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <{https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}s:Envelope>@1:66 in java.io.InputStreamReader@42832a90)
```

Logs after envelope construction:

```
07-07 15:15:22.296: I/GetInfo(29392): Envelope to String: 
07-07 15:15:22.296: I/GetInfo(29392): org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope@42602660
07-07 15:15:22.296: I/GetInfo(29392): request to String: 
07-07 15:15:22.296: I/GetInfo(29392): XMLDataGet{entity=persona; last_update_date=20140101; country=UA; user=someuser; }
```

Comment: @SHIDHIN.T.S, have u managed it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064822/wsdl-soap-request-format-for-android ?

Comment: Please indicate in your code, (after which line), how you determined the `request XML`.

Comment: @greenapps pls explain what do u mean...?

Comment: You said `The application creates the following request XML:`. I want to know where in your code you know it.

Comment: @greenapps okay, so below the 'try' code that i have, there is catch (Exception e) { Log.d(TAG, androidHttpTransport.requestDump); } and here I have this xml.

Comment: I see two try's and no catches. But it does not seem like a good idea retrieving that from a catch. Moreover i wanted to know where you can retrieve it sooner. No not sooner.. The first possible.

Comment: @greenapps, I've updated the code, pls have a look :) thanx

Comment: You are still logging in a catch block. I asked you to log sooner as you have not to put your envelope on transport to begin with. As soon as your envelop is constructed log what is in it. So before using HttpTransportBasicAuth. I would not be amazed if the wrong url is already there right after the line with `SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope`.

Comment: @greenapps, i've put log catches just after envelope construction.

Comment: Well I expect that you comment on the results first.

Comment: @greenapps what results? what do u mean?

Comment: The log catches of course. What else?

Comment: @greenapps i do not understand what still remains unclear for you..